# Key-Value pair Container without the Value

Tags: c#

What container should I use to contain a list of values of MyEnum type, but the container must ensure that a value of MyEnum can only can only appear a maximum of once in the entire container, and each element in the container only contains 1 value? If I use Key-Value pair containers the memory allocated for the value part is wasted.

Summed up: Basically, what container is the same as List in C#, but the difference only being that a value is assured to never appear twice in the container?

Comment: If you want just distinct values in the data store then use a HashSet??? HashSet is an optimized set collection. It helps eliminates duplicate strings or elements in an array. It provides a simple syntax for taking the union of elements in a set. This is performed in its constructor.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I tried googling "Key Container" and all the results that came out were about storing client-server's private keys. HashSet is what I needed.

Comment: Don't beg for upvotes. Probably they will only bring you downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly sure that you're looking for the [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
HashSet<MyEnum> = new HashSet<MyEnum>();
// add them here
```

This collection is very efficient in lookups and ensures that all items are unique. You can try to add an item which was already in the set, then [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `false`.

Since enum is a value type you can use it directly. If you want to use a custom class you have to ensure that it overrides `Equals`+`GetHashCode`. Another option is to pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` to [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This program contains a source array that contains several duplicated strings. It eliminates duplicate strings in the array. The program calls the HashSet constructor to transform the array elements into a set data structure.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Input array that contains three duplicate strings.
    string[] array1 = { "cat", "dog", "cat", "leopard", "tiger", "cat" };

    // Display the array.
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array1));

     // Use HashSet constructor to ensure unique strings.
     var hash = new HashSet<string>(array1);

     // Convert to array of strings again.
     string[] array2 = hash.ToArray();

     // Display the resulting array.
     Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array2));
     }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `ToArray` as `string.Join` will take an `IEnumerable<T>`, which `HashSet<string>` is. (as of .Net 4)

Comment: If only i had the privelage to work with developers such as yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something that is called a [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). Rembember that it's good practice to implement [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) for the objects that you want to use in the `HashSet`.